# Can I generify the following code?

Tags: java, generics, rx-java

I have some methods in a class like this:

```
@Override
public void sendRemoteRecord(String token, int channelId, int eventId, final ServiceCallback<RemoteRecordResponse> callback) {

    epgServicesApiManager.sendRemoteRecord(token, channelId, eventId)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(new Action1<RemoteRecordResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void call(RemoteRecordResponse model) {
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onSuccess(model);
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onError();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void activateRemoteRecord(String token, String cardNumber, final ServiceCallback<RemoteRecordActivateResponse> callback) {

    epgServicesApiManager.activateRemoteRecord(token, cardNumber)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(new Action1<RemoteRecordActivateResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void call(RemoteRecordActivateResponse remoteRecordActivateResponse) {
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onSuccess(remoteRecordActivateResponse);
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onError();
                }
            });
}
```

Is it possible to remove the duplication around the code after the observeOn() line?

The annoying part is making sure I do the null check on the callback before using it.

At present, I know of seven distinct methods I need in this class and possibly more.

Comment: It should be posted in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) community

Comment: Do I have to pay again there?

Comment: Just go through this [tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? There are some nice bits in Java 1.8 that could help, but it may not be worth discussing if you are using 1.7 or prior.

Comment: I'm on android so java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Java 1.7 there is no way to fix this without increasing the amount of code. You *can* reduce the amount of code needed locally, by introducing some helper classes.

One solution is to move your anonymous inner classes to top-level classes. From there you can introduce a dummy callback and some null-checking work an an abstract class.

It may end up looking something like this (horizontal rules are used to highlight that these classes are in separate files).

---

This is a dummy callback class, it does exactly nothing, but is safe to call against. This will replace the `null` values.

```
public class NullServiceCallBack<T> implements ServiceCallBack<T> {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(T target) {}

    @Override
    public void onError() {}
}
```

---

This is an abstract class that handles the validation, converting `null` values to instances of `NullServiceCallback`:

```
public abstract class CallBackAction<T> implements Action1<T> {
    private final ServiceCallBack<T> Callback;

    public CallBackAction(ServiceCallBack<T> callback) {
        this.Callback = (null != callback) ? callback : new NullServiceCallBack<>();
    }

    protected ServiceCallBack<T> getCallback() {
        return Callback;
    }
}
```

---

This is the concrete class you'll use for success.

```
public class SuccessCallbackAction<T> extends CallBackAction<T> {

    public SuccessCallbackAction(ServiceCallBack<T> callback) {
        super(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(T target) {
        getCallback().onSuccess(target);
    }
}
```

---

This is the concrete class for errors. This doesn't do anything with the arguments to call, so we can make this implement for `Object` once and be done with it.

```
public class ErrorCallbackAction extends CallBackAction<Object> {
    public ErrorCallbackAction(ServiceCallBack<Object> callback) {
        super(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Throwable target) {
        getCallback().onError();
    }
}
```

---

So in the end, your example above should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void sendRemoteRecord(String token, int channelId, int eventId, final ServiceCallback<RemoteRecordResponse> callback) {

    epgServicesApiManager.sendRemoteRecord(token, channelId, eventId)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(new SuccessCallbackAction<RemoteRecordResponse>(callback), 
                       new ErrorCallbackAction(callback));
}

@Override
public void activateRemoteRecord(String token, String cardNumber, final ServiceCallback<RemoteRecordActivateResponse> callback) {

    epgServicesApiManager.activateRemoteRecord(token, cardNumber)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(new SuccessCallbackAction<RemoteRecordActivateResponse>(callback),
                       new ErrorCallbackAction(callback));
}
```

Locally, we've reduced the amount of code, and made the intent a little more clear. Globally, we've increased the complexity with the addition of 4 new classes. Whether this is worth it depends on the context your code lives in, and is your call.

Comment: I went with this code minus the dummy callback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a dummy callback that does nothing, then do `safeCallback().onSuccess()` or `safeCallback().onError()`

Also, you can do this:

```
class SuccessCallback<T> extends Action1<T>() {
                @Override
                public void call(T value) {
                    safeCallback().onSuccess(value);
                }
}

class ErrorCallback extends Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(T value) {
                    safeCallback().onError();
                }
}
```

then...

```
subscribe(new SuccessCallback<RemoteRecordActivateResponse>(), new ErrorCallback());
```

Does this work?

Comment: safeCallback(){return callback == null? dummy : callback}